# VS2008 SP1: No appropriate default constructor available when pushing a pair into vector

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, c++03, compiler-bug

#### Background

Class `Foo` has user-declared constructor and thus no [implicitly-declared default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor):

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(...) {...}
};
```

It is then used in the `std::vector` of `std::pair` as follows:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Foo> >
```

#### Usage

Attempting to push back in the vector:

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Foo> > v;
v.push_back(std::make_pair(std::string("some string"), Foo(...)));
```

#### Compilation error (VS2008 SP1)

The following [error C2512](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zkz8dx6.aspx):

```
'Foo' : no appropriate default constructor available
...\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\utility(43): 
while compiling class template member function 'std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair(void)'
```

#### Notes

- [`std::vector` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) says it should accept copy-assignable and copy-constructible objects:

  > **T** must meet the requirements of ***CopyAssignable*** and ***CopyConstructible*** (until C++11).
- The code compiles just fine with gcc and VS2008 (pre SP1).

#### Question

What is causing the error? Is there a bug in VS2008 SP1? If yes, what are the work-arounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### TL;DR

This is a bug in VS 2008 SP1. Simplest possible work-around is providing a default constructor when VS 2008 SP1 is detected.

#### Explanation

After doing some research I found the [thread on msdn forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/34473b8c-0184-4750-a290-08558e4eda4e/vector-pushback-now-requires-default-ctor) describing similar situation. The thread contains an answer from Microsoft employee which provides clear explanation.

Here's the quote (shortened for brevity, emphasis mine):

> Thanks for reporting this bug ... 
>   This was introduced in the Visual C++ 2008 Feature Pack, which was
>   incorporated into SP1.
>
> We used OR here (and in tuple's `_Move_operation_category`)
>   intentionally.  We wanted to consider `pair<int, string>` to be
>   fast-swappable (which it is).  Unfortunately, we forgot that the
>   Swaptimization requires a default constructor, and that pair/tuple
>   allow user-defined types to sneak in.  (With something like `vector<T>`
>   or `shared_ptr<T>`, even if `T` doesn't have a default constructor, the
>   vector or `shared_ptr` does.)  Clearly, this was my bad.
>
> There's a silver lining to this conformance bug: at least this error
>   is letting you know that `vector<pair<foo, wstring> >` will be slower
>   than `vector<wstring>`.
>
> ...
>
> As **workarounds**, you can:
>
> 1. Give foo a default constructor.  This will fast-swap the wstring and general-swap the foo.
> 2. Give foo a default constructor, and a swap() implementation that can be picked up through ADL.  This will fast-swap both the wstring
>      and the foo.
> 3. Write your own pair.  This will disable the "Swaptimization".
> 4. Use `vector<pair<shared_ptr<foo>, wstring> >`.  This will fast-swap the `shared_ptr` and `wstring`.  Of course, now you're doing more dynamic
>      memory allocations, so this is desirable only in certain
>      circumstances.
>
> Note that when we get move semantics, this swap machinery will be
>   eliminated, which is going to be so awesome.

#### A work-around

After considering the work-arounds I went with #1: providing a default constructor if VS2008 SP1 is detected:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(...) {...}
#if _MSC_FULL_VER == 150030729 // Visual Studio 2008, SP1
    Foo() {} //<- work-around for VS2008 SP1 bug
#endif
};
```