# How to insert class objects to map correctly without pointers?

Tags: c++

this is my code:

LoggedUser.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using std::string;

class LoggedUser {
private:
    string m_username;
public:
    LoggedUser(string username);
    string getUsername() const;
    bool operator==(LoggedUser loggedUser) const;
};
```

Room.h

```
#pragma once
#include <LoggedUser.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;
using std::string;

typedef struct RoomData {
    unsigned int id = 0;
    string name;
    unsigned int maxPlayers = 4;
    const unsigned int timePerPlay = 10;
    bool isActive = false;

    RoomData& operator=(const RoomData& roomData) {
        this->id = roomData.id;
        this->isActive = roomData.isActive;
        this->maxPlayers = roomData.maxPlayers;
        this->name = roomData.name;
        return *this;
    }
} RoomData;

class Room {
private:
    RoomData m_metadata;
    vector<LoggedUser> m_users;
public:
    Room(const Room& room);
    Room(RoomData roomData, LoggedUser loggedUser);
    int getUserIndex(const LoggedUser& loggedUser);
    void addUser(LoggedUser loggedUser);
    void removeUser(LoggedUser loggedUser);
    vector<LoggedUser> getAllUsers();

    unsigned int getId();
    string getName();
    unsigned int getMaxPlayers();
    bool getIsActive();
};
```

RoomManager.h

```
#pragma once
#include <map>
#include "Room.h"

class RoomManager {
private:
    std::map<unsigned int, Room> m_rooms;
public:
    void createRoom(LoggedUser loggedUser, RoomData roomData);
}
```

RoomManager.cpp

```
#include "RoomManager.h"

void RoomManager::createRoom(LoggedUser loggedUser, RoomData roomData)
{
    m_rooms[roomData.id] = Room(roomData, loggedUser);
}
```

The problem is in the file RoomManager.cpp
in the function createRoom
i'm trying to insert to the map<unsigned int, Room>,
a room by his id,
but i get this error **"C2512   'Room::Room': no appropriate default constructor available"**

now, i know i can fix this by inserting a pointer of Room instead of the object itself, but i want to know if there is a way to do it without pointers, just so i know what was the problem in my code.
Thanks for everyone who helping.

Comment: Provide a default constructor for `Room`?

Comment: Why not to use constructors for `Room` and others to handle implicit stuff and to use `createRoom` for explicit stuff?

Comment: @churill but i don't get it, look at the Room class, why do i need default constructor also, can you explain?

Comment: if the key is not present in the dictionary operator[] adds it with a default value of the member object. That's why it requires Room to be default constructrable, however, if you use insert instead that requirement is relaxed (Room must be copy constructable). @rveerd answer is the correct one, see my comments below for a working example and a possible explanation of your error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `m_rooms[roomData.id] = Room(roomData, loggedUser);` statement you use the `std::map::operator[]`, which...

> ...returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to
> *(requested)* key, **performing an insertion if such key does not already exist**.

Thus, we may use the operator only if the `mapped_type` has a default constructor. Since to insert a *"fallback"* a value into the `map` (if we access a key that is not in there yet) it will need to default construct one on the fly.

But since you did **provide non-default constructors** for `Room`, the compiler does not synthesizes the default one for you. Thus, the `Room` is not DefaultInsertable.

So we can handle this by simply introducing a [defaulted default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor):

```
class Room {
    // Other private members as before
public:
    // Other public members as before
    Room() = default;
};
```

Lesson learned: `std::map::operator[]` require `mapped_type` to be **DefaultInsertable**. For more, refer to the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/DefaultInsertable).

Comment: ok.., that's fixed the problem, but why is that?, is the map needs a default constructor to sort the elements or something? and what the constructor = defualt, means? what if i create an object like that?

Comment: i just did a default constructor for the class RoomManager but still i get the error, so is the problem in the map itself that must has default constructors?

Comment: @TiZ_Crocodile You need a default constructor in `Room`, as in the answer.

Comment: @TiZ_Crocodile `RoomManager` already has synthesized default constructor, as long as you don't introduce any non-default constructor yourself.

Comment: The lesson learned is wrong: #include <map>

struct Foo { double x; Foo(double v) : x(v){}; };

int main()
{
    std::map<int,Foo> m;
    m.insert(std::make_pair(1,Foo(12.3)));
}

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi already looking into the question!

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi yeah, it is the `[]` that requires that. Just derived that from the docs, while the other answer literally says the same!

Comment: @AlessandroTeruzzi thanks for pointing out! Edited in the correct answer. The research was priceless!

Answer (score 2):

You are using `operator[]` to insert an item into the `std::map`. This operation requires that the inserted item is *DefaultConstructible* [1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).

The `Room` class is not *DefaultConstructibel*, as explained in the other answer by @rawrex.

If you cannot or do not want to add a default constructor, you can also use the `insert()` function to insert an item. This function does not have the above requirement.

```cpp
m_rooms.insert(std::make_pair(roomData.id, Room(roomData, loggedUser)));
```

Comment: @churill not with template, this should be the accepted answer

Comment: @TiZ_Crocodile are you using an old visual studio compiler? I had problem with std::pair requiring the default constructor in C++03 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51282596/vs2008-sp1-no-appropriate-default-constructor-available-when-pushing-a-pair-int